# Input layout, access violation, error handling not working like i want it to

Tags: c++, debugging, error-handling, directx-11

I'm learning DirectX 11, and I wanted to get my head around DirectX debugging because I got an access violation reading location error on line 199 (create inputLayout) 
I am trying to get an error box with directX errors show up because I read somewhere that it is a good programming practice to have that box show up with information about errors
Any ideas?
Also, help with the input layout would be appreciated

```
ID3DBlob *VS, *PS;

#if defined(DEBUG) | defined(_DEBUG)
#ifndef HR
#define HR(x) \
{ \
HRESULT hr = (x); \
if(FAILED(hr)) \
{ \
DXTrace(__FILE__, (DWORD)__LINE__, hr, L#x, true); \
} \
}
#endif
#else
#ifndef HR
#define HR(x) (x)
#endif
#endif

D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"shaders.fx", 0, 0, "VS", "vs_5_0", 0, 0, 0, &VS, 0, 0);
D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"shaders.fx", 0, 0, "PS", "ps_5_0", 0, 0, 0, &PS, 0, 0);

device->CreateVertexShader(VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &vShader);
device->CreatePixelShader(PS->GetBufferPointer(), PS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pShader);

VS->Release();
PS->Release();
context->VSSetShader(vShader, 0, 0);
context->PSSetShader(pShader, 0, 0);


// define the input layout
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] =
  {
    { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
};


UINT numElements = ARRAYSIZE(layout);

//below gives me access violation error and says that &inputLayout is NULL 
HR(device->CreateInputLayout(layout, numElements, VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), &inputLayout));
```

Comment: Code provided from links is considered to be _non existent_ on [so].

Comment: well, sorry i did not know that, and I didnt want to add 500 lines of code to this post, can you maybe help me?

Comment: You're supposed to provide a [MCVE] that reproduces your error here (emphasis on **minimal**).

Comment: fixed, I hope thats better

Comment: Well how did you allocate/instantiate `layout` actually?

Comment: I used a global variable, filled out the input element description,and after creating the InputLayout i used IASetInputLayout

Comment: Show us the code for ``layout``. Also what is the value of ``VS``?

Comment: I added code, VS is of ID3DBlob type

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are releasing the VS blob before you create the layout according to the code above. You need the original Vertex Shader binary blob at the time you create the Input Layout so that Direct3D can validate they match up.

A simple fix is to move `VS->Release();` to after you call `CreateInputLayout`.

A better answer is to remove all explicit use of `Release` an instead rely on a smart-pointer like [Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr).

```
#include <wrl/client.h>

using Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr;

...

ComPtr<ID3DBlob> VS, PS;

...

D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"shaders.fx", 0, 0, "VS", "vs_5_0", 0, 0, 0, &VS, 0, 0);
D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"shaders.fx", 0, 0, "PS", "ps_5_0", 0, 0, 0, &PS, 0, 0);

device->CreateVertexShader(VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &vShader);
device->CreatePixelShader(PS->GetBufferPointer(), PS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pShader);

context->VSSetShader(vShader, 0, 0);
context->PSSetShader(pShader, 0, 0);

...

//below gives me access violation error and says that &inputLayout is NULL 
HR(device->CreateInputLayout(layout, numElements, VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize()));
```

Whenever `VS` and `PS` go out of scope, they will take clear of cleaning themselves up.

Comment: Thank you I will definitely use that!

Comment: You might find [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) and it's [tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) useful.